# Word for "having intension to do something, but do not know where to start"

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes I feel like doing something (let's say writing an article about the lovely weather today) but I do not know what to write. How to describe this phenomenon?

You have the intension to do something, but you do not know where to start.

Comment: Writer's block? Starting trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might say you are *[blocked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blocked)*, *[frozen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frozen#Adjective)*, *at an [impasse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impasse#Noun)*, or *[at a loss](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+a+loss)* (“unable to know how to act or what to do”).

If it is due to lack of knowledge, consider *[clueless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clueless#Adjective)*; if due to lack of direction, *[rudderless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rudderless)* or *[drifting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drifting)*; or if due to lack of insight, *[uninspired](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uninspired)*.